# Pvk2Pfx won't use input PVK password for output PFX protection

Tags: x509certificate

I am using [Pvk2Pfx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/hardware/ff550672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert a pvk and cer to a pfx file, the command I am using is

```
pvk2pfx -pvk MyTest.pvk -spc MyTest.cer -pfx MyTest.pfx
```

During the creation of pvk file by using `makecert`, I was prompted to enter a password for private key.

When I ran the command to convert, I was also prompted to enter the password of the pvk file. When I tried to import the pfx file to my certificate store in Windows, I don't have to specify the password. But according to Microsoft document

> /po pfxpassword Specifies a password for the .pfx file. If a password for the .pfx file is not specified, the password for the .pfx file will be the same as the password for .pvk file

In this case I have not used /po switch in my command, I think the pfx file should have the same password of pvk file, right? Why I don't need to provide password to import it to certificate store?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it will only use the password for the .pvk file as password for the .pfx file if you provide the password using the /pi switch.

```
pvk2pfx /pvk pvkfilename.pvk /pi pvkpassword /spc spcfilename.cer /pfx pfxfilename.pfx
```

If you don't specify a pvk password, you will be promted to input one, but the resulting pfx file will NOT be password protected.

[Additional info about pvk2pfx.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/hardware/ff550672(v=vs.85).aspx)